# Why asp:ContentPlaceHolder on the title replaces the whole title?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.Net MVC on my Site.Master I have:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /> - MySite</title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

then on each view I have something like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home
</asp:Content>
```

and I was expecting, as a result:

```
 <title>Home - MySite</title>
```

but instead I've got:

```
 <title>Home</title>
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
<title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="titleContent" runat="server" />
  <%= "- My Site" %>
</title>
```

The reason is that everything rendered in the head is rendered as a control.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674902/appending-to-default-title-in-asp-net-masterpage/1021013#1021013) for some further links, and other ways of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a Title attribute in the <%@ Page %> directive.

Comment: I did have a Title there, but removing it didn't help. What should I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

wired I had the same issue and I end up using this format

```
   <title><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Title"])  %> - mysite</title>
```

in this way the title is controlled through the controller

Comment: Arguably the view should be responsible for determining the title and not the controller.

Comment: I wouldn't even say "arguably."  Titles are most certainly view logic, and probably 95% of the time, a dynamic title is based on your model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking the `runat="server"` bit out of the head tag?  I don't have a machine to test on right now, but that looks a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

I use this markup in Site.Master file:

```
<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text=" - MySite" />
</title>
```

It looks similar to boymc's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030063/why-aspcontentplaceholder-on-the-title-replaces-the-whole-title/1030537#1030537).